# Tabbed View Controller, changing text in another view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm making a tabbed application, and i came across an issue.

I have a button on one tab, when it is clicked, it's doing something in the current tab. my problem is that I want to, in addition to that, it would change the text of a label in a different view (the second tab)

Can anyone give me some directions?
xcode 4.2 ios 5.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about a `UITabBarController`. If that is the case, you can access all of the view controllers housed by the tab bar like this:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];
```

That gives you an array of the view controllers. Just get the view controller you want, and access the label's property and do whatever you want with it.

EDIT: Access the view controller like this:

```
ParkerAssistantSecondViewController *vc = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
vc.label.text = @"Some Text";
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access a property in it? [viewController objectAtIndex:1].label.text? doesn't work for me, what m I missing?

Comment: Is `label` a property of whatever view controller you're accessing? You need to define the property in the view controller using `@property` and `@synthesize`.

Comment: it is defined and synthesized in the second view controller, which I want to access from the first one.

Comment: Try logging `[viewController objectAtIndex:1].label`. Does it return a `UILabel` object, or is it `null`?

Comment: It won't let me log it. it says it can't find the property.
When I simply log the [viewController objectAtIndex:1] it gives <ParkerAssistantSecondViewController: 0x6b219f0> does it matters where i place the NSArray *viewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers]; ? I placed it in the viewDidLoad of the first one

Comment: Ah, okay. You need to cast the view controller. See the edit on my answer.

Comment: Now I can access the properies, but when I write the vc.label.text u wrote, nothing changes on the other tab. in the storyboard the labels are linked to the IBOutles..

Comment: Try logging `vc.label.text` to see if the text is actually being set.

Comment: My guess is that you haven't linked the label to the property.

Comment: appears so, even thru the second controller itself setting the text returns null...
I relinked them and still no good..
I click control and then draw the line from the second view controller to the label and select the property.. missing something?

Comment: Solved, I think. I was declaring the property as strong. changed to retain and it works

Comment: I'm getting another problem, it works while doing so from the second view controller itself, but not using the initial intention from the first one.

Comment: Got this one.. the first view controller loads before the second one, so it's null... silly me.
all good now.
Thanks man!